# Has the State Department submitted any reports to Congress under 22 U.S.C. § 1741 (aka “Hostage Recovery and Hostage-Taking Accountability Act”)?

Tags: united-states, congress, state-department

According to [this law (22 U.S.C. § 1741)](https://casetext.com/statute/united-states-code/title-22-foreign-relations-and-intercourse/chapter-23-protection-of-citizens-abroad/subchapter-ii-hostage-recovery-and-hostage-taking-accountability/section-1741-assistance-for-united-states-nationals-unlawfully-or-wrongfully-detained-abroad) an annual report to Congress needs to be submitted by the State Department, listing United States nationals they consider wrongfully detained abroad.

Have any such reports been submitted insofar?

(As far as I can tell the law passed [in 2020](https://www.congress.gov/bill/116th-congress/senate-bill/712/text) but I'm unsure what is the first year for which a report needs to be submitted.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer appears to be... maybe.

The US State Dept [has a whole section on their website for "hostage recovery"](https://www.state.gov/subjects/hostage-recovery/), that lists other efforts to identify and return Americans held abroad. The oldest post is from February 2, 2021, which leads me to suspect this "tag" came into being so they could at least start something in compliance with the law.

I cannot find any formal reports to Congress on this.